# trying to get the value of php into javascript

Tags: javascript, php

I'm trying to get value of the `$dateyearrange` to put in `yearRange`:
For example my `$dateyearrange = 2001`
then the `yearRange:'dateyearrange:+0'` should be `yearRange:'2001:+0'`
but I can't seem to make it work

#### Edit: the problem in my code is in  `yearRange:('dateyearrange:+0')`

If I put echo `<?php $Dateyear ?>` the code wouldn't execute
because if I use `yearRange:dateyearrange` the ouput on the yearrange is only **2001** which is the code is working fine. so the problem in my code is in `yearRange:`
What i wanted is to be shown in `yearrange` is `2001:+0`

I'm so sorry for my english I can't really explain myself to it.

### EDIT 2:(Solution):

I use `yearRange:"<?php echo $DateYear ?>:+0"` and removed `var dateyearrange = "<?php $Dateyear ?>";`
I just made my code more complicated I don't know why I go in that way. Thanks for the replies it helps me.

```
<?php
$DateYear = date("Y", strtotime($Datebirth)) 
;?>
var dateminimum = "<?php Echo($Datebirth); ?>";
var dateyearrange = "<?php $Dateyear ?>";
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate:dateminimum, maxDate:'0', yearRange:('dateyearrange:+0'), dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true});
  });
```

Comment: The syntax is <?php echo ?> or <?php print ?> or <?= ?>

Comment: echo $Datebirth -- echo $Dateyear

Comment: if I put echo in $Dateyear the code won't work.

Comment: I use `yearRange:"<?php echo $DateYear ?>:+0"`
I' just made my code more complicated I don't know why I go in that way. Thanks for the replies it helps me.

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$DateYear = date("Y", strtotime($Datebirth)) 
;?>
var dateminimum = <?php echo $Datebirth; ?>;
var dateyearrange = <?php echo $Dateyear ?>;
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate:dateminimum, maxDate:'0', yearRange:('dateyearrange:+0'), dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

Change it to :

```
<?php
$DateYear = date("Y", strtotime($Datebirth)) 
;?>
var dateminimum = "<?php echo $Datebirth; ?>";
var dateyearrange = "<?php echo $Dateyear; ?>";
  $(function() {
    $( "#datepicker" ).datepicker({minDate:dateminimum, maxDate:'0', yearRange:('dateyearrange:+0'), dateFormat: "yy-mm-dd",changeMonth: true,
      changeYear: true});
  });
```

Answer (score 0):

You still need to `echo` or `print` or `=`

```
var dateminimum = "<?php echo $Datebirth; ?>";
var dateyearrange = "<?php echo $Dateyear; ?>";
```

Comment: You can't use the var `dateyearrange` inside quotes without escaping it `('dateyearrange:+0')` would be something like `(dateyearrange+':+0')`